# Update XML Clob node

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, qxmlquery

I have a table Transaction , in which I have a clob xclob for which ,

I want to update the  "property"  node's "record_start_dll_date" value to record_start_date(i.e I want to remove the _dll part )
and "record_dll_end_date" to record_end_date .
I am using oracle database . How can I modify these node values??

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<properties>
   <property name ="record_start_dll_date">
   <value>1/1/2021</value>
   </property>
    <property name ="record_dll_end_date">
   <value>21/12/2021</value>
   </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you want. Are you changing the attribute names, to effectively remove the `_dll` part? Or changing the values of those nodes to different dates - in which case where do those new dates come from? If there are multiple CLOBs do they all need the same changes, to attribute or value? And are you updating the CLOB value in a table, or just as it is queried?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes I want to remove the _dll part from the attributes name .

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks A lot , with your help finally I updated my records .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XMLQuery update, either with the specific attribute values:

```
xmlquery ('copy $i := $p1 modify (
  (for $j in $i/properties/property[@name="record_start_dll_date"]/@name
    return replace value of node $j with $p2),
  (for $j in $i/properties/property[@name="record_dll_end_date"]/@name
    return replace value of node $j with $p3)
  ) return $i'
  passing xmltype(xclob) as "p1",
    'record_start_date' as "p2",
    'record_end_date' as "p3"
  returning content)
```

or to strip any `_dll`:

```
xmlquery ('copy $i := $p1 modify (
  for $j in $i/properties/property[contains(@name, "_dll")]/@name
    return replace value of node $j with replace($j, "_dll", "")
  ) return $i'
  passing xmltype(xclob) as "p1"
  returning content)
```

Either way you can incorporate that into an update statement, with a matching XMLExists clause to avoid unnecessary updates:

```
update transaction
set xclob = xmlquery ('copy $i := $p1 modify (
  for $j in $i/properties/property[contains(@name, "_dll")]/@name
    return replace value of node $j with replace($j, "_dll", "")
  ) return $i'
  passing xmltype(xclob) as "p1"
  returning content).getclobval()
where xmlexists('$p1/properties/property[contains(@name, "_dll")]'
  passing xmltype(xclob) as "p1")
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc68eabe95f8f71fe64fb95925a0d48a)